Auditd log format ENRICHED and syslog-ng
I want to send audit data to a syslog trap using syslog-ng.
It works, but since I set the log_format option to enriched in auditd.conf the log in the /var/log/audit/auditd.log contains both enriched and non-enriched data
type=PATH msg=audit(1713273080.150:8936624): item=0 name="/var/log/audit/.audit.log.swp" inode=2359490 dev=08:01 mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=0:0:0:0 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0^]OUID="root" OGID="root"

However, my syslog trap receive only non-enriched part before the group separator symbol 0x1D (^]).
I have tested the trafic with tcpdump ( sudo tcpdump -i any udp port 5051 -w syslog.pcap  ) and as far as I see in the resultant pcap file, the part after the group separator symbol is not sent.
Is there a way to make syslog-ng send the whole message including enriched data?

Hi, can you share a bit more details about your syslog-ng config? How are you reading/parsing/sending the logs? Do you use the auditd parser (https://axoflow.com/docs/axosyslog-core/chapter-parsers/linux-audit-parser/)?
